# setBalloon callback in google earth

Tags: angularjs, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I'm working in google earth with angularjs. 
I'm tring to put directive into balloon but it's dosent succses.
After I tring to put with angular.element the directive by $compile service.
it's succses but it's change on the old balloon and not on the new one.
If have any callback or event to setBalloon ? or any other idea? 
Tanks a lot 
Refa !!